# should I add a "the" before "paths of length 2"?

Tags: grammar, determiners

I am confused for these situations:

1. Preparing desirable paths needs to iterate all possible paths

   (the) desirable paths;  all (the) possible paths;

   I have described what a desirable paths is. "all possible paths" denotes paths that may exist in a graph.
2. Although using paths of length 2 to construct features is much easier than using longer paths,

   (the) paths of length 2; (the) longer paths;

   "paths of length 2" denotes paths whose lengths are 2 (in a graph).

I think that "paths" are not specific. But when I add "desirable" or "of length 2", is that "paths" is specific for "desirable" or "length 2"?

Comment: Could you make this a little clearer by providing complete sentences in which you want to use these phrases?

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question. Could you have a look again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language used in proofs, or in the descriptions of algorithms, tends to state general truths when possible. So phrases like "all possible paths" or "paths of length 2" are fine as long as you are not referring to specific paths or sets of paths you have previously described.

Looking at your specific examples:

> **Preparing desirable paths needs to iterate all possible paths**

"all possible paths" is fine; for example it would be used in this description of an exhaustive graph search:

> To find the shortest path, enumerate all possible paths, keeping track of which path is the shortest.

If there is a set of possible paths and the algorithm requires examining them one at a time, usually you would say *iterate over* and not just *iterate*.

Your use of *needs* in this sentence is incorrect; a step in a process isn't described as *needing* another step. There are a few different ways this can be described, depending on exactly what you are expressing:

If you are describing the steps involved in preparing desirable paths:

> In order to prepare the desirable paths, first iterate over all possible paths.

(Note that here it is *the* desirable paths, because in this context you are describing a step in a process operating on some specific paths).

If you are stating in general what is involved in preparing desirable paths (for example, as part of calculating the complexity of the preparation):

> Preparing desirable paths requires iterating over all possible paths.

If you are stating what must have happened before any desirable paths could be prepared:

> Preparing desirable paths requires that all possible paths have been iterated over.

So whether you need to use *the* before *desirable paths* depends on exactly what you are expressing.

> **Although using paths of length 2 to construct features is much easier than using longer paths,**

This is fine as-is, assuming you are stating a general truth about constructing features. If you are describing steps in a feature construction algorithm and have (for example) already defined a set of length 2 paths, you might say:

> ... using *the* paths of length 2 to construct *the* features ...

And if you had described these length 2 paths immediately before this sentence, you could even say:

> ... using *these* paths of length 2 ...

which would emphasize exactly which paths you meant.

But it sounds like you are probably making a more general statement, so the version in your question in fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have known what a general statement is with your help.